# How to correctly decode/encode file names when using `pdfrw` to add metadata?

Tags: python, pdf, unicode, character-encoding, pdfrw

I'm writing a script that will add PDF metadata to a list of PDFs.

My problem is dealing with PDFs with names that have certain characters in them -- in the example I tried, the name had an "en dash" in it, but I'm sure in the future (I don't control these file names) there will be other similar issues.

I'm using `pdfrw` and Python 2.7. Currently I have:

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader,PdfWriter
from os import listdir

def get_files(pwy):
   tr_files=listdir(pwy)
   tr_files2=[]
   for t in tr_files:
      tr_files2.append(pwy+'/'+t)
   return tr_files2

def add_keywords(filename,keywords):
   writer=PdfWriter()
   trailer=PdfReader(filename)
   trailer.Info.Keywords=keywords
   writer.trailer=trailer
   writer.write(filename)

file_list=get_files('C:/example_folder')
for f in file_list:
   add_keywords(f,'some exciting metadata!')
```

This works fine for files without the "en dash". The files with the "en dash" shows that it was modified when I run this, but when I check the metadata in Adobe Acrobat, there's nothing there.

I'm pretty sure this is an encoding problem of some kind. Since it shows the "en dash" as `x\96`, it must be using cp1252. I'm using Spyder 2.3.1 and I have # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the top of my script.

I read through [The Absolute Minimum Every Softward Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) and I know, in general, I want to decode the input, run the rest of the code (not printed above, but I use the file name to extract information from a database, then format that information and want to put the resulting string into the metadata), and then encode it again. But I haven't been able to figure out anything that works.

I think the solution is going to be one of the following:

1. [best] Correctly deal with the encoding issue.
2. Run some sort of batch file on the subfolder renaming the files to something the script can handle, then reverse the names at the end (they need to end up with the original file names).

I appreciate any help! I haven't been able to find anything that's worked.

Answer (score 1):

You freshly acquired Unicode knowhow will not help you with PDF. PDF came into being before there was Unicode.

You should look up *"Annex D (normative): Character Sets and Encodings"* in the official [ISO 32000_2008 PDF-1.7 specification as published by Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=659), from page 651.

There you'll find you should use for *en-dash*:

- `\263` for StandardEncoding
- `\230` for MacEncoding
- `\226` for WinEncoding
- `\205` for PDFEncoding

For Metadata (`/Info` dictionary) use the PDFEncoding.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem here, because the encoding issue isn't with the PDF metadata, it's with the PDF name as read in. What I think is happening is that the file is called something like hello--world.pdf and it's trying to write to hello\x96world.pdf which, of course, doesn't exist. I think the PDF metadata is actually tangential to this problem -- it's only relevant because I'm using the pdfrw package, and so I thought how it writes to files might matter.

Comment: Your $headline clearly talks about *"encode file names using `pdfrw` to add metadata"*. So my answer is applicable.

Comment: To be fair, it says "encode file names WHEN using pdfrw to add metadata." So I could definitely improve my question-headlining-skills, but it was not incorrect. The using pdfrw to add metadata was to add context.

Comment: My answer has broader implications than just the metadata. I pointed you to the ***only*** 25 pages with a few huge tables which are relevant for your problem, and which show you that neither utf8 nor direct hex encoding are involved.

Answer (score 0):

More along the lines of your second solution - can you copy the file to another path inside of `add_keywords`, then do the `PdfWriter` stuff, then copy it back?  You can use `tempfile.mkstemp()` to get a temporary filename, or if you're only going to be doing one at a time, just pick a name somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation yet for stackoverflow to let me comment on the problem, so this is more of a comment than a real answer. (I am the pdfrw author.)

"The files with the "en dash" shows that it was modified when I run this, but when I check the metadata in Adobe Acrobat, there's nothing there."

That's really odd.  Are you sure you're seeing the modification time, or are you seeing the access time (e.g. for some reason the read works, but the write doesn't)?

Anyway, the thing I would like to suggest (for debugging purposes) is that you start off by replacing "writer.write(filename)" with something like "writer.write('modified_' + filename)"

You could also print the filename in the loop to make sure that those files are really being seen.

Finally, the filename handling in pdfrw is really basic, but if you need to for some reason, you can open files yourself and pass in the file objects to the reader and writer.